# IPMI not fucntioning with Network Bonding

Tags: ipmi

I am having problems with running IPMI on my servers that have network bonding enabled.

> Platform: CentOS release 5.3 (Final)
>   Kernel: 2.6.18-92.el5
>   64bit Dell PowerEdge 1950
>   Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5708 Gigabit Ethernet

I  have bonded the interface eth0 and eth1 as active passive, with eth0 as the active interface, below is conf description from /proc

> Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance
>   (active-backup) Primary Slave: eth0
>   Currently Active Slave: eth0 MII
>   Status: up MII Polling Interval (ms):
>   30 Up Delay (ms): 0 Down Delay (ms): 0
>
> Slave Interface: eth0 MII Status: up
>   Link Failure Count: 0 Permanent HW
>   addr: 00:22:19:56:b9:cd
>
> Slave Interface: eth1 MII Status: up
>   Link Failure Count: 0 Permanent HW
>   addr: 00:22:19:56:b9:cf

My IPMI device is as follows

> IPMI Device Information
>           Interface Type: KCS (Keyboard Control Style)
>           Specification Version: 2.0
>           I2C Slave Address: 0x10
>           NV Storage Device: Not Present
>           Base Address: 0x0000000000000CA8 (I/O)
>           Register Spacing: 32-bit Boundaries

I Have used openIPMI as well as freeipmi both to control the chassis via the IPMI card, but on servers which have bonding enabled, the command times out, below is the full run of the command with debug info.

> ipmi_lan_send_cmd:opened=[0],
>   open=[4482848] IPMI LAN host
>   70.87.28.115 port 623 Sending IPMI/RMCP presence ping packet
>   ipmi_lan_send_cmd:opened=[1],
>   open=[4482848]   No response from
>   remote controller Get Auth
>   Capabilities command failed
>   ipmi_lan_send_cmd:opened=[1],
>   open=[4482848]   No response from
>   remote controller Get Auth
>   Capabilities command failed Error:
>   Unable to establish LAN session Failed
>   to open LAN interface Unable to get
>   Chassis Power Status

On the other hand I configured IPMI on a box with the same specs as mentioned above without bonding and IPMI works perfectly.

Has anyone faced this problem with IPMI + Bonding ? 
I would be thankful is someone helps circumvent this issue.

- Muhammed Sameer

Comment: See: http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/linux-poweredge/2005-October/022934.html

Comment: In my case inspite of the eth0 being the active interface , IPMI  still does not seem to work  


Below is the dump from /proc that confirms that eth0 is active  


Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance  
(active-backup) Primary Slave: eth0  
Currently Active Slave: eth0 MII  
Status: up MII Polling Interval (ms):  
30 Up Delay (ms): 0 Down Delay (ms): 0    

Slave Interface: eth0 MII Status: up    
Link Failure Count: 0 Permanent HW  
addr: 00:22:19:56:b9:cd    

Slave Interface: eth1 MII Status: up    
Link Failure Count: 0 Permanent HW  
addr: 00:22:19:56:b9:cf

Answer (score 1):

We have encountered this problem with our Supermicro systems when using IPMI over LAN1 (rather than IPMI with a dedicated LAN). We did some debugging here: http://pastebin.com/gsmr9WvS

We are in talks with Supermicro at the moment to isolate the issue, but for now remains to be an issue that cannot be resolved due to the mac sharing between both NICs.